# IP Lookup in PHP from JavaScript returning undefined

Tags: php, json, undefined, ip-address, lookup

I'm trying to do an iplookup from script.js through a call to my own server, but all that is returned is 'undefined'. Why?

**iplookup.php**

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $data = json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    //next line needs to be commented out
    //echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
?>
```

**script.js**

```
//get ipaddress
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/iplookup.php",
    data: null,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp'

}).done(function (json) {
    self.ip = json;
});
//on the next line it returns `undefined`  
console.log('ipaddress: ' + self.ip);
```

Comment: Because you're not echoing anything out in your PHP.

Comment: Why `jsonp`? Where exactly does it return `undefined`?

Comment: what is the response with $data when you try echo it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the response out also. Right now what you are doing, is that you set header, encode $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to $data variable, but you neber echo it out. So your javascript ajax request gets only a empty response.

do like so:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");
print json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

?>
```